# How to Model Last Values for Missing Weekend Data

Tags: oracle, analytics, data-modeling

I'm trying to create a query that will carry data forward to null rows.  This is a fairly simple query with [analytic functions LAG and LEAD](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2010/06/simulating-laglead-ignore-nulls.html)

The query works when there is no partition by window and only one security_id.  But, when I add that partition by and a second security_id, the last_value function fails.  The bold rows do not appear.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image]

```
select t.*
,last_value(weight_pct ignore nulls) over
    (partition by security_id order by n desc) value1 from (         
select 
datekey,portfolio_id,security_id,weight_pct
, n
 from (       
select to_date(first_date, 'yyyymmdd') -
                      to_date(datekey, 'yyyymmdd') day
                     ,datekey
                     ,portfolio_id
                     ,security_id
                     ,weight_pct
                from ((select FIRST_VALUE(datekey) OVER(ORDER BY datekey desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as first_date,
                              datekey,
                              portfolio_id,
                              security_id,
                              WEIGHT_PCT
                         from foo d
                        where security_id in (7,658900)
                          and portfolio_id = 2))) d
        right outer join (select level as n
                          from dual
                          connect by level <= 95) l
          on d.days = l.n) t
        order by n, security_id, datekey desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set an `IGNORE NULLS` On line 2?